# Conceptually, what is Logcat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using `Log.d(DEBUG, msg:"My message");` in my code for debugging purposes. Then I am running Logcat which results in "My message" being displayed. I am wondering what Logcat means and does from a conceptual standpoint. I understand this is relatively vague but would appreciate any sort of explanation or link here that can be understood by a beginner. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Logcat essentially prints out a log of necessary information specified by you or in certain APIs. Think of it like `System.out.println()` in Java (in fact you can actually do this to print out logs. This will show up in the Logcat as well). The Logcat is very useful in debugging since you can log data values to see if things are being set or you can log exceptions.