# How to retreive all data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Studio and Firebase.

I am trying to retrive data from Firebase. I have node `Orders` and that node has unique `id`, `choices` and `price`.

This is how my Firebase looks like:

```
my-application0-8b65a
    Orders
        - Lw4hgcNwuCitXUKHdNh
          choices:"Pasta\n"
          price:19
        - Lw7zID257gZsJN9s0J3
          choices:"Shawarma\nPasta\n"
          price: 27
```

I have tried to use `addValueEventListener` to retrieve all orders from University, but when I run the app and go to the retreiving page, it goes back to main activity page. I am using listview(id:list_view) to display the data.

[image: code]

```
public class DataRetrived extends AppCompatActivity {    

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ListView mUserList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dataactivity);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mUserList = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        final List<Orders> ordersList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                ordersList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Orders orders = postSnapshot.getValue(Orders.class);
                    ordersList.add(orders);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

Log.e("Count " ,""+snapshot.getChildrenCount());

for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {

```
<YourClass> post = postSnapshot.getValue(<YourClass>.class);

Log.e("Get Data", post.<YourMethod>());
```

}

}

@Override

public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());

}

});

Answer (score 0):

First add a reference to node `Orders` and then inside onDataChange remove the for loop to be able to retrieve the object `Orders`.

Change this:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

into this:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
```

Then change the `onDataChange()` to the following:

```
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          ordersList.clear();
                Orders orders = snapshot.getValue(Orders.class);
                ordersList.add(orders);
        }
```

Comment: check the logcat

Comment: remove the extra semi colon here `private ListView mUserList;` also inside `onCancelled` write `throw databaseError.toException();`

Comment: app still crashes on this page.

Comment: again you need to check the logcat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850695/conceptually-what-is-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: it shows many errors,i cant understand it.Is there any other way i can contact you?

Comment: you need to create an adapter `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.ListView,StringArray);` and then set the adapter `mUserList.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: is their any problem?

Comment: i tried this still it crashes.                                                                                         mUserList = findViewById(R.id.list_view);                                                   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.dataactivity, (List<String>) mUserList);
 mUserList.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: please check the logcat when it crashes, you will find an error

Comment: if you cannot do the above, then remove the addvalueeventlistener and run the application

Comment: in logcat im not getting any caused by error,tried both.

Comment: yes it was,THANK YOU i tried everything again and it worked.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct since it helped you